# How can I retrieve a word in a string using the word after it in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to create a code where I search the name and I get the word before it. I'm struggling with making the code work.
This is the code I have so far.

What can I put after the `if v == position:` to make it works?

```
TV= \
'''
Tulleveien Velforening
leder: Kari
kasserer: Ole
IT-ansvarlig: Liv
parkeringsansvarlig: Kari
arrangementsansvarlig: Liv
hagekonsulent: Kari
brannansvarlig: Kari
'''

def verv(navn):
    splitit = TV.split('\n')
    splitlines = len(splitit)
    position = 0
    liste = []
    for v in splitit:
    if v == position:

        print(v)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split each line using the ": " delimiter, do get a list with the role and the name. Then you can check the name and add it to the list.

Please note that I did changes to the `TV` string to remove excessive newlines.

Code:

```
TV= \
'''\
Tulleveien Velforening
leder: Kari
kasserer: Ole
IT-ansvarlig: Liv
parkeringsansvarlig: Kari
arrangementsansvarlig: Liv
hagekonsulent: Kari
brannansvarlig: Kari\
'''

def verv(navn):
  splitit = TV.split('\n')

  liste = []

  for row in splitit:
    parsed_row = row.split(': ')

    if len(parsed_row) == 2 and parsed_row[1] == navn:
      liste.append(parsed_row[0])

  return liste


print(verv('Kari'))
print(verv('Liv'))
```

Output:

```
['leder', 'parkeringsansvarlig', 'hagekonsulent', 'brannansvarlig']
['IT-ansvarlig', 'arrangementsansvarlig']
```